# Boost ASIO multicast failure on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, boost, boost-asio, multicast

I have an application written for both Windows and OSX which uses Boost ASIO for networking. Part of this application sends a multicast message out for embedded devices to respond to :

```
std::string ip_addr = "224.0.0.177";
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint senderEndpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip_addr), 7076);
m_pcDiscoverySocket->send_to(boost::asio::buffer((void*)pGetDeviceInfoMessage->m_pchData, pGetDeviceInfoMessage->m_ulDataSize), senderEndpoint);
```

This code works absolutely fine on Windows. It also works fine on OSX, but only when there is a DHCP server on the network. When there is no DHCP server on the network and everything has auto-ip allocated addresses 169.254.x.x then the send_to function throws an exception with the error message "send_to: Network is unreachable". If I change the IP address in the above code to 169.254.0.1 then it runs with no error messages, but the embedded devices obviously don't respond as it's not a broadcast IP address.

I'm a bit baffled. Can anyone explain why it's throwing this error, or why the same code works in Windows (running in a VM on the Mac with identical hardware)?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of fruitless searching and a few experiments I think I've found a solution which involves changing the last line of the code in the question to :

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(m_IOservice);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(),"");
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::ip::address interface_ip_address;

while(it!=boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator())
{
    interface_ip_address = (it++)->endpoint().address();
    if(interface_ip_address.is_v4())
    {
        m_pcDiscoverySocket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface(interface_ip_address.to_v4()));
        m_pcDiscoverySocket->send_to(boost::asio::buffer((void*)pGetDeviceInfoMessage->m_pchData, pGetDeviceInfoMessage->m_ulDataSize), senderEndpoint);
        break;
    }
}
```

Basically, it seems that on OSX you have to tell the socket which interface to use, but only if it's not got its IP address via DHCP. This also appears to work on Windows (though it did before too).

If someone smarter than me can explain why this works and why you have to do this on OSX then I'll give them the credit for the answer.

Comment: The default route on OSX (and Linux) is setup based on the interface status.  For DHCP, usually the default interface is set properly, without DHCP, the default interface is likely not set or not set to route your multicast traffic.  Things get even worse with multiple adapters.